# Django Model Multi Select form not rendering properly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to display all the categories to appear as a list that I can click and select from, just an exact replica of what I have in my admin panel, but it still display's as a list that isn't clickable.

**forms.py**

```py
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for updating Profile data
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Profile

        fields = [
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "about_me",
            "profile_image",
            "username",
            "email",
            "categories",
        ]

    first_name = forms.CharField(label="First Name", max_length=63, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label="Last Name", max_length=63, required=False)
    about_me = forms.CharField(label="About Me", max_length=511, required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", disabled=True)
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", disabled=True)
    profile_image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    )
```

**profile.models.py**

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=63, blank=False)
    about_me = models.CharField(max_length=511, blank=True)

    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        Category, related_name="user_categories", symmetrical=False
    )
```

**categories.models.py**

```py
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=63)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

**settings.html**

```html
<div class='row'>
            <div class="col s12 m6">
              {{form.categories.errors}}
              {{form.categories.label_tag}}
              {{form.categories}}
            </div>
</div>
```

**What I hope to achieve**
[image]

**What I get**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the form itself:

```
<form method='post'>

</form>
```

And print each field on a new line:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

is a security check.

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

In the view, I left get_context_data. In it, you can add values ​​to the context, for example, like this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        context['rubrics'] = Car.objects.all()
```

**Replace bboard with the name of the folder where your templates are placed.**
I have this: templates/bboard which are in the application folder.

In the view for the form, the [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) class is used, in which: template_name - the name of the template for displaying the page, form_class - the form class is indicated, success_url - where to return in case of successful saving of the form (in this case, this is the same page with the form), get_context_data - the template context (you can print it out and see what's inside).

And if your model has fields: first_name, last_name, about_me, email, username, profile_image, then it is enough that you have specified the fields variable in the class Meta class. You don't need to re-create them in the form.

```
template_name = 'bboard/tam_form.html'#bboard replace with your prefix
```

Templates

```
<form method='post'>
    {{form.categories.errors}}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value='adding'>
</form>
```

views.py

```
from .forms import *
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class Profile(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/settings.html'#bboard replace with your prefix
    form_class = ProfileEditForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('test')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        return context
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
           path('test/', Profile.as_view(), name='test'),
]
```

**Update 13.11.2022**
This is how my form looks like when I go to the address:

```
http://localhost:8000/test/
```

[image]

But the form is not submitted. I don't have much experience with this. I can assume that forms.ModelForm expects that the model has such fields, because if you delete the lines with email, username, profile_image and also remove them from the fields and add 'user' to the field, then the data will be saved in the database (checked).

As I said earlier, if the fields are declared in fields, then you do not need to define them again (if you leave them, the form will also be saved). This is what the form class looks like:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile

        fields = [
            'user',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'about_me',
            'categories',
        ]

    categories = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks but I have done all that, I only included the necessary files in this question but still can't figure out the above error.

Comment: @osahenru show the models you use.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question with the models.py file, really looking forward to a reply from you.

Comment: Show the Category model too.

Comment: Oh, that has been updated too, hoping to get something positive out of this. Thanks

Comment: Well thanks for the effort, I'm not sure you got the question right, but thanks all the same.

Comment: Let's do it easier, show how the category looks like in the admin panel.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding the list of categories